# How to access solaris 10 gui from windows machine?

Tags: windows, solaris, remote-access, opensolaris, solaris-10

I want to access solaris 10 GUI screen from my windows xp machine.
Is there any software which can provide this flexibility ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Assuming your Solaris box has X already installed:

1. Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) on your Windows machine
2. While installing, once you get to the packages page, make sure that X11 is set to Install so that you get all X11 packages
3. Once Cygwin is done installing, run Start->All Programs->Cygwin-X->XWin Server
4. Follow [these directions](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-remote-apps.html) (copied below for convenience)
5. Type `ssh -Y username@[solaris box ip]`
   (note you may need to run `/usr/openwin/bin/xhost +` first)
6. Run any program which can use X11 (i.e. `/usr/openwin/bin/xclock` on my Solaris)
7. It should display in a GUI windows

Comment: i am getting "unable to open display <my ip>:0.0"...any idea why?

Comment: Try searching online `"unable to open display" ":0.0"`. There are plenty of discussions with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

[CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) comes with an X display server so you should be able to run that, set up a `DISPLAY` variable to your Windows box (on the Solaris box) and run any GUI program you want.

For example, download CygWin using that link above, then install *everything,* not just the default packages.

Then start up the X server on your Windows box by choosing `Start`, `All Programs`, `Cygwin-X` and `XWin Server`.

Now, let's say your Windows IP address is 192.168.31.31 - you would, on the Solaris box, do something like:

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.31.31:0.0
xeyes &
```

That should run xeyes (or whatever *actual* program you want to run) on your Solaris box, while putting the window (and input) for it on your Windows box.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply...will you please provide better steps how do i proceed with it ? do i need to install CygWin on both side ?

Comment: No problem, @yakub_moriss, I added some more detailed steps.

Answer (score 1):

Just install [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/). It is free and much easier to use than any of the other recommendations you got, IMHO. It is a terminal emulator (based on Pytty), an X Server, etc, all in one easy to use package.